# Proxy External Rest API using Istio

Tags: istio, http-proxy, istio-gateway

I'm using Istio to manage the K8S micro services but there are some rest APIs (https) which is running outside K8S cluster.
Now I want to proxy these APIs through Istio instead of calling them directly.
Eg:

1. all apis are using 'api.xyz.com' as domain.
2. Now if someone calls 'https://api.xyz.com/v2/review' then it should go to service which is deployed in K8S cluster. This is working for me (using virtual service & gateway)
3. Now if request comes to 'https://api.xyz.com/review' (no v2 here) then I want to send that request to external API 'https://execute.abc.com/v1/review' (here 'v1' is added so we need to rewrite the url as well) and whatever response comes, it should be returned.
   I tried using ServiceEntry but not getting any success. I'm new to Istio so not sure what I'm missing here.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a ServiceEntry and Destination rule for `execute.abc.com` for the 443 correct port according to istio documentation.

It should be created in a namespace where the gateway is defined. If your gateway is defined in `istio-system` then create the objects as follows:-

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata: 
  name: execute-domain
  namespace: istio-system
spec: 
  hosts: 
    - execute.abc.com
  ports: 
    - number: 443
      name: https-execute-domain
      protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  exportTo: 
    - "."
```

The destination rule can specify certificate if your mode is TLS: SIMPLE
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#ClientTLSSettings
You can use existing cacert at the ingressgateway or you can specify credentialName and deploy a secret with key cacert:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: DestinationRule
metadata: 
  name: execute-domain
  namespace: istio-system
spec: 
  host: execute.abc.com
  exportTo: 
  - "."
  trafficPolicy: 
    tls: 
      mode: SIMPLE
      sni: execute.abc.com
      caCertificates: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs/cacerts
```

then in your virtual service you can add this before your v2 route. In VS the sequence is important. If it finds a match it will take that 1st.

So that would look something like this:-

```
    - match:
        - name: execute-external-route
        - uri:
            prefix: /review
      rewrite:
        uri: /v1/review
        authority: execute.abc.com
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 443
            host: execute.abc.com
    - match:
        - name: review-k8s-route
        - uri:
            prefix: /v2/review
      rewrite:
        uri: /
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 80
            host: review-service.<your namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to configure caCertificates? execute.abc.com is signed by the external known certificate authority.

Comment: Currently I'm trying to run using the config suggested (except caCertificates) and I'm getting 503 NC cluster_not_found error

Comment: okay. My service was in different namespace so I just remove the exportTo. After I see that request is going to upstream. It's giving 403 now.

Comment: The external endpoint is AWS API Gateway. Direct API is working but through istio, it's giving 403.

Comment: I suspect your 403 may be because of TLS settings and combination of certificates.

Comment: You check debug istio-proxy logs to understand the 403. Other pointers:- You might want to specify `credentialName` which is a name of a secret. This secret should be key/value pair - at the minimal your you need key `cacert` (check the istio docs I can't remember the key name)